# .NET settings.settings Variable Confusion

Tags: .net, settings

I'm new to WPF applications and I am dealing with an app that is storing some simple variables in settings.settings via the grid GUI in Visual Studio.

The problem is that somehow two boolean variables have been set to true, and I can't seem to reset them. If I go back to the setting GUI, I can see that the value is set to "False", but when loading the settings variables during debugging, it shows them being set to "True".

How can I reset these variables to False outside of the Settings GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have an app.config stored for your user which might overwrite the default values. Or dito for app.config for the executable.

Comment: I checked the appSettings in the solution and the variables correspond with the settings GUI (False), still showing "True".

Comment: If you have the settings in a dll file, you have also checked the app.config/web.config for the executable/website that references your dll? Have you checked the settings for the current user? See this article: http://www.blayd.co.uk/article.aspx?pageid=1013

Comment: The True values were coming from user.config in my local appdata folder. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

They must be in the app.config or web.config of the executing assembly, you must copy that config to it if the settings are in another assembly. What you set in the GUI is the default value for those variables.

Comment: There are several projects in the solution, but the appsettings file under this particular project shows the variables as "False"

Comment: You must see app.config in the project that is executing, not the others. There must be no or incorrect setting in that config. Copy the config from the project with the setting to the executing one and change the values

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check whether these variables are set to `True` in your [app.config](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/123/) file.